# How can hide url value in php

Tags: php, http, url, web

i done a project in php i want to hide my URL in address bar how can i hide any one help me please

http://www.mysite.co.in/tempserv/bos/fm/index.php?page=reports&pageid=2&uid=109"

this is my URL i want to show to users up to index.php only like

http://www.mysite.co.in/tempserv/bos/fm/index.php How can i hide this

Comment: Then try `post` instead of `get` or try to `encrypt decrypt url`

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459984/php-hide-url-get-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Use POST method instead of GET.
Eg.

-----------
-----------
-----------

Comment: i want value send only anker tag not form...like.. <a href="xyz.php?r=122">aa</a>                                       thanku.

Comment: You could have use url encoding like  "base64_encode"  and base64_decode. It will show some random string instead of correct content in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use the POST method

```
<form action="#" method="post">
.......
</form>
```

and in the php use in an string to receive POST method

```
$var = $_POST['name_input'];
```

Comment: i want value send only anker tag not form...like.. <a href="xyz.php?r=122">aa</a>                                       thanku.

Comment: Its is a GET, not POST.
You need, in your php, change the '$_POST' to '$_GET'. Sample: '$var = $_GET['r'];. You receive in your $var = 122