# hide project id from URL only show project name

Tags: php

i dont want to show  id from url like :http://localhost/project_name/project_detail.php?id=190 i have to send only project name from url http://localhost/horisolto/project_detail.php_project_name on next page i am not using any framework like MVC how can i pass project name and behind hide project_id please help me...thanks in advance

Comment: Use post request instead of get if necessary.

Comment: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: You are saying that every project name in your db is unique?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - hide url (GET) parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459984/php-hide-url-get-parameters)

Comment: @plum project_name is not unique i have search project by their id but through the url i want to hide project id and only show project name.

Answer (score 0):

just update config of your web server
For nginx use

```
rewrite ^/project_name/project_detail.php_([^/]+)/?$   project_name/project_detail.php?id=$1;
```

for apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
rewrite ^/project_name/project_detail.php_([^/]+)/?$   project_name/project_detail.php?id=$1;
```

Note: for apache you can use it in .htaccess file

after this you must find your project by "project name" instead of id

Comment: is it really possible to hide the id like this.

Comment: @Aleksey but i want search project by their project_id it is possible to hide id from url.(project_id_is necessary

Comment: You can encrypt the id, and the server to decrypt it, but it's stupid.
Your server must understand that he look, and if you do not pass id him then he will have to look for another option

Answer (score 0):

create a .htaccess file in your root and add the following code:-

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^project/([A-Za-z0-9-]) project-details?pid=$1    [L,QSA,NC]
```

In the loop where the projects are listed, change their href's to project/project-name/3.