# collect date from URL usign GET method and Change Full URL in PHP

Tags: php, url

I collect product_id & count_id valu from get method and url redirect or show plan url

when user Click/Browse this link Example:
http://www.website.com/index.php?product_id=1&count_id=1023

then user view in the browser and will be shown as:
http://www.website.com/

User can't view **index.php?product_id=1&count_id=1023** extra url in the Browser. And My Site index.php will collect **$product_id** , **$counter_id**  from URL and use some function or echo **$product_id** , **$counter_id**.

and if possible want to set **$product_id** , **$counter_id** data in cookies.

Comment: You want to extract these info from the url?

Comment: its not clear what you are trying to say.....

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to hide the GET parameters then it's already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24460228/5788489)